# How to get values of Heikin Ashi bar from a chart with candles bar?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am using normal candles on my chart, but I want to make some calculations with Heikin Ashi bar.
I would like to get the color of the previous day Heikin Ashi bar.
Is that possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tradingview user Allanster shared a open source multi timeframe(to access the daily data) heikin-ashi pinescript here:

https://www.tradingview.com/script/HtNYMuBO-Heikin-Ashi-Source-Function/

what you are looking for is in line 39:

```
upBar = preEvalC > preEvalO
```

boolean upBar indicates the green Heikin Ashi candle.

Comment: Thank you. The line was number 30.